# MySQL combining multiple rows into one row

Tags: mysql, join, rows

I've two tables as below:
1. tbl_student:

```
id  name
1   raj
2   raja
3   raju
4   rajan
```

2. tbl_attendance

   ```
    id student_id month attended_days
     1          1     1             6
     2          1     2            16
     3          8     1             8
     4          7     2            14
     5          8     2            13
     6          7     1            11
   ```

I need to join these two tables combining multiple rows for each month for each student from tbl_attendance into a single row to obtain a result like this:

```
 id     name    month   attended_days   month   attended_days
  1     raj         1               6       2              16
  7     raja        1              11       2              14
  8     rajan       1               8       2              13
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think it would help if you added some code showing what you tried (and failed), this will increases the chances that you get an answer

Comment: How many `month` columns should your result contain in the end?

Comment: What you need is a pivot table. This can be achieved by creating a prepared statement that would returned the results for you in the format you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of displaying month value in each of the records,
you can use them as column headers and attendance as their value.

Use *pivot* type solution to achieve required solution.

**Example**:

```
select s.id as student_id
     , s.name as student_name
     , max( case when a.month = 1 then a.attended_days else null end ) as month_1
     , max( case when a.month = 2 then a.attended_days else null end ) as month_2
     , max( case when a.month = 3 then a.attended_days else null end ) as month_3
--     ...
     , max( case when a.month = 12 then a.attended_days else null end ) as month_12
  from table_student s
  left join table_attendance a on s.id = a.student_id
 group by s.id, s.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very complete, but i think you want something like this:

```
 select s.*, 
    coalesce(a1.month, a2.month, a3.month) as month,
    coalesce(a1.attended_days , a2.attended_days , a3.attended_days ) as attended_days 
     from table_student s
      left join table_attendance a1 on s.id = a1.student_id and a1.month = 1
      left join table_attendance a2 on s.id = a2.student_id and a2.month = 2
      left join table_attendance a3 on s.id = a3.student_id and a3.month = 3
```

The previous code is used if you want to show all months in one column. For multiple columns, you can use this example:

```
  select s.*, 
    a1.month as month_1, 
    a2.month as month_2,
    a3.month  as month_3,
    a1.attended_days as attended_days_1, 
    a2.attended_days as attended_days_2, 
    a3.attended_days as attended_days_3  
     from table_student s
      left join table_attendance a1 on s.id = a1.student_id and a1.month = 1
      left join table_attendance a2 on s.id = a2.student_id and a2.month = 2
      left join table_attendance a3 on s.id = a3.student_id and a3.month = 3
```

Do this for all the 12 months. I used 3 as example.